# How do I disconnect this water fitting?

Tags: plumbing, connectors

I found this on a hot water inlet under a sink. The front works like a standard push-to-fit. The back I'm not quite sure. I don't know if that grey piece is just a clip on that locks the push to connect release or something else. I don't want to force it and break it then have to tear open the wall to replace a chunk of the inlet. Can anyone confirm what it is? Thanks for your help.

[image]

Comment: This is your hot water _supply_ line? This fitting goes into the faucet above the sink? That's unusual, is the cold water side the same? Can you give us a wider pic showing all the plumbing under the sink including this one.

Comment: Is the black part a continuous ring all the way around? If so, turn it CCW and see if the white part  releases by pulling.

Answer (score 1):

The black ring with the tab looks like a lock. Slide a screwdriver under the tab from the side and pry gently to lift it, then pull it completely off.